# calling a library inside an interrupt

Tags: function, arduino, interrupt

I have this code here that when the button is pressed the LED will blink for 3-10 seconds and then stay on for 15minutes. Now, what i want to do is, how can I call the tinyGPS.h to execute exactly after the 3-10 seconds of blinking time? i have created a function but i have no luck.

```
#include "TinyGPS/TinyGPS.h"

int buttonPin = 0;    
int ledPin = 1; 
int held = 5;
int ledState = LOW;         
int buttonState;             
int lastButtonState = LOW;   
long lastDebounceTime = 0;  
long debounceDelay = 50;   

void setup() 
{
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
}

void loop() 
{
int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    if (reading != lastButtonState) 
        {
            lastDebounceTime = millis();
        } 

    if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) 
        {
            if (reading != buttonState) 
                {
                    buttonState = reading;
                    if (buttonState == HIGH) 
                        {
                            int cntr=10;
                            do
                            {
                                digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   
                                delay(200);  
                                digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    
                                delay(200);                
                                cntr = cntr-1;
                            }       
                            while (cntr!=0);
                            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
                            delay(900000);
                            ledState = LOW;
                        }
                }
        }

  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  lastButtonState = reading;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but... Where is the interrupt you spoke about in the title?

Anyway... If you want to execute ONCE a function just before starting your 15 minutes wait, you can put it before the instruction `delay(900000);`.

However if you want to do something in this 15 minutes you can't use a `delay` function, because it is a blocking function. You have to

1. wait for shorter times and then executing something or
2. use the `millis()` function, as suggested by the "blink without delay" example.

I suggest you the second solution, because you have a more precise wait time and, well, it's the RIGHT way to do that.

Or, better, the best solution is not having a code like yours, but implement a finite state machine with the elapsed time as a parameter to change state.

If you just expect everything on a plate, I can write you the solution 1: instead of `delay(900000);` write

```
int time_cnt;
for(time_cnt=0; time_cnt<900; time_cnt++)
{
    // Do something
    delay(1000);
}
```

This executes the `Do something` part once per second; you can extend the time or shorten it according to your needs...

Comment: how can i set the button to held, like i want the button to be pressed for 5seconds? It goes like this, the same time the LED is to blink for 5 seconds same goes for button to be held.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand well. Anyway for your problem I suggest a state machine template. And then use millis to trigger the state transitions..